# ScrollView inside another scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

[image: Two Scroll Views]

I have two `UIScrollViews` (red and yellow). Red is a subView of Yellow and grey is my device screen.  I'm able make the scrolling works in both directions (vertical & horizontal), but there is one problem... Vertical scroll only works if the horizontal is SCROLLED FIRST?

Both of these views are NOT the firstResponder.  I tried setting `[yellow becomeFirstResponder]` but it returned NO.

How do I make either `UIScrollView` scrollable upon user's touch?

Comment: Can you share code related to this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by following code

```
UIScrollView *scrollYellow = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 250, 480)];
[scrollYellow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[scrollYellow setContentSize:CGSizeMake(250, 800)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollYellow];

UIScrollView *scrollRed = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 250, 200)];
[scrollRed setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[scrollRed setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 200)];
[scrollYellow addSubview:scrollRed];
```

hear in **`scrollYellow`** make `width` of `frame` & `ContentSize` same
and in **`scrollRed`** make `height` of `frame` & `ContentSize` same